# Remaining days in a Year

Tags: c++

I want to get the Remaining days in a  Year and my code is almost complete but i get error, It gives me wrong output.

For Example (mm-dd-yy) 3-18-2013 and the output suppose to be 288 but mine is 275..

here are just some of my code

```
void dateType::Num_RemainingYear()
    {
        int yy=365;
        int sum;

        if(month==0)
        {
            day=0;
            cout<<"Number of days Remaining in the year: "<<day<<endl;
        }


         else if (month ==1)
        {
            day=31;
            sum=yy-day;

            cout<<"Number of days Remaining  in the Year: "<<sum<<endl;

        }...until 12
```

[Output Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxSEQ.jpg)

Comment: Links to code, or anything essential to interpreting the question, are a bad idea because when the link rots the question becomes useless.

Comment: Step through your code with the debugger that almost certainly came with your development environment (upgrade if your development environment is one of the few that doesn't have a debugger) until you see where the program doesn't do what you expected. Then figure out why it didn't do what you expected.

Comment: research to do: time(0), 'localtime_r', and "struct tm'.

Comment: tagged as C++:  see std::time()

Comment: If you offer "just some of your code" you can get "just some of an answer". The code you've shown is enough to conclude you've picked a pretty horrid way of solving the problem. But not enough to identify all your mistakes. Where does `month` come from for instance? What I do suggest however, is that if you pass a date parameter to your method, it will be much easier to test for "number of days in year at different dates" (regardless of what the current date is).

Comment: [Full code](http://ideone.com/NQSpit) here my code so you can check out

Comment: Links to code, output etc - as you've already been told - are inferior to creating a complete, self-contained question.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fairly complicated. How about just adding all the days that have passed since the 1.1 of the year and subtracting that from 365/366?

Without lep years, here is how it could look like:

```
int daysPassed = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < month; i++) {
    if (i == 2)
        daysPassed += 28;
    else if (i < 8 && i % 2 == 1)
        daysPassed += 31
    else if (i < 7)
        daysPassed += 30;
    else if (i % 2 == 0)
         daysPassed += 31;
    else
         daysPassed += 30;
}
daysPassed += day;
```

Comment: this is the only way i can think off

Comment: just go through every month that has passed and add the days together. subtract the final value from 365/366 and you're done. quick and easy

Comment: so i am confused what you mean, can give me a snap of the code? i have to stick and just modified my code (if else statement)or make new one?